# MySql: Copy sql rows and keep some fields the same while updating others

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with three columns, I want copy/paste all three columns within the same table, however, of the three columns, I want to update two columns with new data specific for that day while keeping one column the same.  For the following table:

```
ticket_number | book_id | log_id
------------- | ------- | ------
            1 |       1 |    120
           12 |       2 |    120
           23 |       3 |    120
```

I want to:

1) Copy all columns and paste into the same table

2) change the `ticket_number` column with new data for that day (e.g. 2, 13, 25) as well as the `log_id` column with the id for the current day (e.g. 121), while keeping `book_id` column the same.

I have tried with no avail:

`INSERT INTO ticket (ticket_number, book_id, log_id) SELECT (2,13,24), (book_id), (121) FROM ticket;`

This the schema for reference

[image]

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also, which DBMS?

Comment: This is my very first post so thanks for that. The DBMS is MySQL

Comment: I am trying to keep track of ticket numbers every day.  Tickets belong to distinct books.  Thus, the books column will remain the same, though every day, the ticket # as well as the log will change.  The (2,13,24) are the updated values for the ticket #'s and the 121 is the updated value for the log.

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECT query needs to return the rows that you want to insert.

UPDATE: You can use a separate table, which might be easier. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE id_map (
old_ticket_number NUMBER,
new_ticket_number NUMBER
);
```

You could insert the values into this table.
You can then use this query:

```
INSERT INTO ticket (ticket_number, book_id, log_id)
SELECT 
m.new_ticket_number,
t.book_id,
121
FROM ticket t
INNER JOIN id_map m ON t.ticket_number = m.old_ticket_number;
```

Does this so what you're looking for?

Comment: When I try that I get:
`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE,
book_id,
121 FROM ticket' at line 7`

I can understand the logic of your statement but it may get difficult to individually hard code the CASE as my data is coming from a REACT front-end in the form of an array and my actual application has around 70 tickets.  Is there an alternative to updating each value one-by-one.  Do you think creating a new table instead of updating the old may be a better option?

Comment: I see. I think creating another table to hold the mapping between the old and new IDs could be a better option. You can then write a SELECT query to get the IDs. I've updated my answer.